# Anti XSS library decode

Tags: c#, decode, antixsslibrary

I am using microsoft anti xss library to form security. I am using HtmlFormUrlEncode method.

How can I decode my recorded data?

sample data :

```
mail%40sample.com
%c3%96nder
```

Comment: I have a very very bad solution : return encodedString.Replace("%c7%b4","Ǵ").Replace("%c7%b3","ǳ").Replace("%c7%b2","ǲ").Replace("%c7%b1","Ǳ")...

Answer (score 7):

AntiXSS doesn't provide a decode - the .NET framework tends to do it for you. Indeed, [UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx) should actually get it correct.

However, if you want to do it manually should be able to create a char[] array that's the same length as the original string, then loop through the string, looking for a % and then grabbing the two characters after, ensuring they're valid hex and then doing the following to get the hex value

```
if ((h >= '0') && (h <= '9'))
{
    return (h - '0');
}
if (((h >= 'a') && (h <= 'f')) ||
    ((h >= 'A') && (h <= 'F')))
{
    return ((h - 'a') + 10);
}
```

Once you have both values you'd then combine

```
byte b = (byte) ((firstByte << 4) | secondByte);
```

And append it to the array by calling [UTF8Encoding.GetChars()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.getchars%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

(note: Code is off the top of my head and not tested properly)